# Minimum iOS required for AirPods Pro 2

Tags: iphone, ios, airpods

I'm using iOS 15.5 on iPhone 13 and when I connected my AirPods Pro 2 to it, the iPhone warned that certain features needed a higher iOS version. I tried to find the specific version that is required for AirPods Pro 2, but Apple.com just said "latest iOS", which is iOS 16 right now. I do not want to upgrade to iOS 16 since there are still many bugs left to fix, e.g. some users experience really poor battery life.

Can anyone confirm what is the minimum iOS version that is fully compatible with AirPods Pro 2?

Comment: If you're on the latest iOS 15 and it shows the message, isn't the minimum iOS 16?

Comment: @JBallin No, I'm not on the latest iOS. So that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Why don't you try updating to the latest version of iOS 15 then? BTW you're putting yourself at risk by not having the latest security patches (which should be included in the iOS 15 updates too).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I updated to iOS 16 and that seemed to solve all the problems I have. Specifically, in iOS 15:

- The AirPod is not listed as a device in "Find" on iOS and macOS
- "Days left to purchase AppleCare" is stuck at 61 days
- The AirPod does not have the correct icon / shape in menu and settings, both iOS and macOS
- Other small, weird things

So, the minimum iOS version needed for AirPods Pro 2 (full functionality) is iOS 16.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question asked.

Comment: @DougMasters How about now?

Comment: "Apple.com just said "latest iOS", which is iOS 16 right now." was already part of the question, somehow.

Comment: @nohillside So should I delete this answer?

Comment: I still think @Allan has the right answer. He answered the question you asked  with receipts. His answer also said an update would fix which it did because that’s what you said.

Comment: @DougMasters Part of his answer is factually incorrect (compared with the link included) and Allan seemed to reject my edit. Am I doing something wrong here? If so I will delete my answer and accept his.

Comment: From my POV it looks like he answered the question you asked which was the MIN version of iOS. To be honest, your answer doesn’t answer the question asked. It basically describes what you did and the things it fixed that was not  in the OP.

Comment: Oh, what part is incorrect?

Comment: @DougMasters "Some features require iOS 13 or iPadOS 13 or later, which are not compatible with iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6, iPhone 5s, iPod touch (6th generation), iPad Air (1st generation), iPad mini 3, and iPad mini 2." This sentence is present in AirPods (2nd gen) page, and not present in AirPods Pro (2nd gen) page. This sentence is where he got his answer of iOS 13.

Comment: On the page for AirPods Pro 2, it lists the 6s as the earliest phone and that max  OS is 13.  Is that statement wrong?

Comment: @DougMasters The max iOS version for 6s appears to be iOS 15. See bottom of apple.com/newsroom/2021/09/ios-15-is-available-today which states "iOS 15 is a free software update that is available starting today for iPhone 6s and later. For more information, visit apple.com/ios/ios-15. Some features may not be available in all regions or all languages."

Answer (score 3):

> I tried to find the specific version that is required for AirPods Pro 2, but Apple.com just said "latest iOS"… Can anyone confirm what is the minimum iOS version that is fully compatible with AirPods Pro 2?

#### iOS 13 for most functionality

Technically speaking, there is no minimum iOS version as they will function as simple Bluetooth headsets with their functionality limited if the device is non-Apple or a pre-iOS 13 device.

The earliest iPhone supported is the 6s which has a maximum iOS version of 13. Per the technical specifications page, Audio Sharing isn’t supported on iPhone models 6s through 7Plus.

In the fine print on the [Technical Specifications page](https://www.apple.com/airpods-pro/specs/):

> AirPods can be used as Bluetooth headphones with Apple devices using earlier software and with non-Apple devices, but functionality is limited

And then in the following point:

> Some features require iOS 13 or iPadOS 13 or later, which are not compatible with iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6, iPhone 5s, iPod touch (6th generation), iPad Air (1st generation), iPad mini 3, and iPad mini 2.

So, we can extrapolate from this that the limits are *hardware* related and the **minimum iOS version is iOS 13** and a device capable of running that version (or later).  To get the Audio Sharing feature, you’ll need iOS 14 or later (and a device that supports it).

#### iPhone reports AirPods need higher version of iOS

> I connected my AirPods Pro 2 to it [iPhone 13], the iPhone warned that certain features needed a higher iOS version.

As for the issue you’re experiencing, there’s no setting or anything user accessible that will modify what gets reported between the accessory (AirPod) and the iPhone.  If the iPhone doesn’t correctly detect the AirPod firmware or vice versa, you can start with removing the paring, a restart of the devices and a re-pairing of the AirPods to the iPhone.

I hesitate to tell you to reinstall iOS because you’ll likely undertake this with Apple Support should you decide to open a ticket; I don’t want to make you do this twice.   However, if you do decide to go this router, *make a backup of your iPhone first!*<sup>†</sup>

To verify that the AirPods are working, you can try pairing them to a different iPhone (running iOS 13+, of course).  If they fail there as well, you may have faulty AirPods.

---

<sup>†</sup> (IMO) This is likely a bug that is fixed with subsequent versions/updates to iOS that you’re currently using. If you happen to open a support ticket, Apple will likely recommend “update to the latest version.”

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @DougMasters I disagree. I consider the "find my" function of AirPod an important part of its full functionality, which is missing in iOS 15 / only present in iOS 16. Therefore, this answer is wrong in stating iOS 13 for full functionality. Specifically, the link is to AirPods (2nd gen), not AirPods Pro (2nd gen). This answer does not apply to AirPods Pro (2nd gen).

Comment: Find my is a function of iOS not the AirPods.

Comment: @Allan Consider removing your point about iOS 13 as I can't find that fine print in the page you linked to. I think the iOS 13 point is based on the information in the older, incorrect link.

Comment: If you read the supported devices, you’ll see that the 6s is listed.  The maximum iOS version for the 6s is 13.  My information is correct.

Comment: I agree with @Allan that Find feature was an IOS feature.

Comment: @Allan the max iOS version for 6s appears to be iOS 15. See bottom of https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2021/09/ios-15-is-available-today/ which states "iOS 15 is a free software update that is available starting today for iPhone 6s and later. For more information, visit apple.com/ios/ios-15. Some features may not be available in all regions or all languages."

Comment: @Allan I'm considering closing or deleting this question because there is no definitive answer. It is ambiguous what I mean by "fully compatible", as that can mean "fully supports all features", and therefore the correct answer would be iOS 17 for Adaptive Audio (which might change again in the future should Apple add new functionalities). What do you think I should do?

Comment: It’s a perfectly valid question.  Maybe you should qualify the question further like you did in your comment.  Remember, you asked about the *minimum* requirements and not the recommended requirements to get full functionality.   It’s a good question….it got 3 upvotes.